# Кто поймёт, по какой причине выдаёт ошибку при нажатии на TwoLineAvatarIconListItem? Python KivyMD

Tags: python, kivymd

Текст ошибки:

```
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\messendger\messenger on android and ios (kivy)\main_mobile_v0.5_2.py", line 120, in switch_screen

self.root.ids.scroll_view.ids.screen_manager.current = {

File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
```

Код:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import (
    MDNavigationLayout,
    MDNavigationDrawer,
    MDNavigationDrawerMenu,
    MDNavigationDrawerHeader,
    MDNavigationDrawerDivider,
    MDNavigationDrawerItem,
)
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineAvatarIconListItem, ImageLeftWidget, TwoLineAvatarIconListItem, \
    OneLineListItem


class BaseNavigationDrawerItem(MDNavigationDrawerItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = 24
        self.text_color = "#4a4939"
        self.icon_color = "#4a4939"
        self.focus_color = "#e7e4c0"


class DrawerLabelItem(BaseNavigationDrawerItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.focus_behavior = False
        self._no_ripple_effect = True
        self.selected_color = "#4a4939"


class DrawerClickableItem(BaseNavigationDrawerItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ripple_color = "#c5bdd2"
        self.selected_color = "#0c6c4d"


class SOTO_Messendger(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return(
            MDScreen(
                MDScrollView(
                    MDScreenManager(
                        MDScreen(
                            MDList(
                                TwoLineAvatarIconListItem(
                                    ImageLeftWidget(
                                        source="img/logo.png"
                                    ),
                                    text="Screen 1",
                                    secondary_text="Твой маршрут на сегодня:",
                                    on_release=self.switch_screen,
                                ),
                            ),
                            name="scr 1",
                        ),
                        MDScreen(
                            MDLabel(
                                text="Screen 2",
                                halign="center",
                            ),
                            name="scr 2",
                        ),
                        id="scroll_view",
                    )
                ),
                MDNavigationLayout(
                    MDScreenManager(
                        MDScreen(
                            MDTopAppBar(
                                title="СОТО Мессенджер",
                                elevation=4,
                                pos_hint={"top": 1},
                                md_bg_color="#e7e4c0",
                                specific_text_color="#4a4939",
                                left_action_items=[
                                    ['menu', lambda x: self.nav_drawer_open()]
                                ],
                            )

                        )
                    ),
                    MDNavigationDrawer(
                        MDNavigationDrawerMenu(
                            MDNavigationDrawerHeader(
                                #source="logo.jpg",
                                title="Иванов Иван Иванович",
                                text="Таб №" + "9999",
                                spacing="4dp",
                                padding=("12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"),
                            ),
                            DrawerClickableItem(
                                icon="send",
                                text="Входящие",
                            ),
                            DrawerClickableItem(
                                icon="send",
                                text="Настройки",
                            ),
                            MDNavigationDrawerDivider(),
                        ),
                        id="nav_drawer",
                        radius=(0, 16, 16, 0),
                    )
                ),
            )
        )

    def nav_drawer_open(self, *args):
        nav_drawer = self.root.children[0].ids.nav_drawer
        nav_drawer.set_state("open")

    def switch_screen(self, instance_list_item: OneLineListItem):
        self.root.ids.scroll_view.ids.screen_manager.current = {
            "Screen 1": "scr 2", "Screen 2": "scr 1"
        }[instance_list_item.text]
        self.root.children[0].ids.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

SOTO_Messendger().run()
```